# Wysiwyg Editor not properly displayed after adding javascript files to head

Tags: layout, adminhtml, wysiwyg

I am adding a wysiwyg editor to one of the page in admin panel. The editor displays properly before I the javascript files to head section. After adding the javascript files in the layout file, the layout of the page goes into the editor. However, I just copy and paste the code from another custom module and it works properly in that module without any warning message. How to fix it? Thank you in advance.

Warning Message in Console

```
tiny_mce.js:1 'webkitMovementX' is deprecated. Please use 'movementX' instead.
tiny_mce.js:1 'webkitMovementY' is deprecated. Please use 'movementY' instead.
```

Before adding the javascript files to head section

[image: Before adding javascript files]

After adding the javascript files to head section

[image: After adding javascript files]

layout.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<handleName_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="module/adminhtml_block01" name="block01"/>
    </reference>
</handleName_index>
<handleName_edit>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setCanLoadExtJs"><flag>1</flag></action>
        <action method="setCanLoadTinyMce"><flag>1</flag></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/variables.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/widget.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>lib/flex.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>lib/FABridge.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/flexuploader.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/browser.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/window.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>prototype/windows/themes/default.css</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>prototype/windows/themes/magento.css</name></action>
    </reference>
</handleName_edit>
```

Form.php

```
class ModuleName_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

protected function _prepareForm() {
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $this->setForm($form);

    if(Mage::registry('module_data')) {
        $data = Mage::registry('module_data')->getData();
    }

    $wysiwygConfig = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig();
    $wysiwygConfig->addData(array(
        'add_variables'             => false,
        'plugins'                   => array(),
        'widget_window_url'         => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/widget/index'),
        'directives_url'            => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg/directive'),
        'directives_url_quoted'     => preg_quote(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg/directive')),
        'files_browser_window_url'  => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg_images/index'),
    ));

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldSet('module_form', array('legend' => 'Editor'));
    $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Title',
            'name' => 'title'
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('content', 'editor', array(
        'name' => 'content',
        'label' => 'Content',
        'title' => 'Content',
        'style' => 'width:700px; height:150px;',
        'wysiwyg' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'config' => $wysiwygConfig
    ));
    $form->setValues($data);
    return parent::_prepareForm();

}

protected function _prepareLayout() {
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->isEnabled()) {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadTinyMce(true);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change one thing

Replace this

```
$fieldset->addField('content', 'editor', array(
        'name' => 'content',
        'label' => 'Content',
        'title' => 'Content',
        'style' => 'width:700px; height:150px;',
        'wysiwyg' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'config' => $wysiwygConfig
    ));
```

with

```
$fieldset->addField('description', 'editor', array(
        'name' => 'content',
        'label' => 'Content',
        'title' => 'Content',
        'style' => 'width:700px; height:150px;',
        'wysiwyg' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'config' => $wysiwygConfig
    ));
```

You will need to change 'content' title to other title as I changed it to 'description'.